# How to limit of members to get AD (az ad group member list --group) AZURE

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get members from a specific group on AD. It gives me memory error as I have too many members in there. I m new to this and learning on the go.

I was hoping to know is there any way to get list for example top 100 and then 100-200, 200-300 and so on.

```
az ad group member list -- group {groupName}
```

Comment: You could try piping to `Select-Object -First 200`, that should stop the pipeline and consume less memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried With Az command in every possible way it is giving me result with all the parameter when I am trying to filter the result it is showing blank and unexpected output. Below commands which I have tested in my environment.

***Output1***

[image]

[image]

As a workaround would suggest you use `PowerShell` command getting the correct output—

Use `Connect-AzureAd` to connect with **Azure ActiveDirectory**.

[image]